# Message is not getting masked automatically in Chrome and IE in Extjs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, extjs, onload

I am having problem with the Iframe in Extjs. Below is the code snippet that works fine in Firefox but does not work in IE and in Chrome. The "msg" should be hidden automatically once the download is started. Please suggest what is wrong with the below code.

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'button',
    icon: 'images/interface-icons/page_white_magnify.gif',
    text: t['generateReport'],
    width: 100,
    handler: function(me) {
        // Loding Mask
        myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {msg: "Please wait...preparing to dowload csv file."});
        window.myMask.show();
        var url = getBaseURL() + 'index.php?r=admin/administrativeReport';
        downloadUrl = url;
        var downloadFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
        downloadFrame.setAttribute('src', downloadUrl);
        downloadFrame.setAttribute('id', "i_frame");
        downloadFrame.setAttribute('class', "screenReaderText");
        downloadFrame.setAttribute('onload', "setFrameLoaded()");
        document.body.appendChild(downloadFrame);
        setTimeout(function() {
            myMask.hide();
        }, 600000);
    }
}]


function setFrameLoaded()
{
   window.myMask.hide();
}
```

Comment: Im having the same issue? Any workaround?

Comment: have you found the solution,I am also facing same issue.